# Anaconda - can I copy envs folder?

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I would like to copy one of the folders in envs to clone the environment somebody else built. However, when I do that and activate the environment, the libraries are still not found by the code that I am trying to run. These are things like keras, h5py, etc. It would be great to avoid reinstalling all of these because I am not sure what versions were used. I can see all the libraries when I browse the site-packages folder of the environment. Is there any way to "install" these, such that the code that uses these can be run? I did try exporting the environment and then creating it from the yaml file - no luck. Creating a text file and then making the environment from that didn't work either.
Thanks!

PS: I also tried reinstalling Anaconda in case some other thing was messed up, but it looks the same.